# Find overlapping lines in same layer

Tags: qgis, line, topology, overlapping-features

I try to identify overlapping lines in the same layer with QGIS.

My problem is that the lines are the same shape but not the same length. Maybe you can understand it with the picture below.

These are two lines and I want something that shows me that the blue line overlaps the orange one. I have a huge network of lines and a visible solution doesn't work.

I tried topology rules with QGIS but there is no suitable rule for them. The blue line is not a duplicate of the orange one. Then I tried the `Check Geometries Plugin` but it doesn't work either, because the lines don't intersect.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a similar question. So, does anyone have an idea? Maybe with a python script? I'm not good enough to write a script by myself.

[image]

Comment: Give a look to this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224289/how-to-select-intersecting-lines-in-the-same-shapefile

Comment: Your example misses an important piece of information: can those lines also share a *common, overlapping part*, or do some represent *subsets* of longer lines only?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

(***update***)

For finding overlap (and not report lines that cross or touch) within a layer, it is good advise to use the QGIS DB Manager and SQL.
For instance:

```
select l1.id as id1, l2.id as id2,
  st_intersection(l1.geometry, l2.geometry) as geometry
  from lines l1, lines l2
  where
    (st_overlaps(l1.geometry, l2.geometry) or
     st_contains(l1.geometry, l2.geometry) or
     st_within(l1.geometry, l2.geometry)
    )
     and l1.id < l2.id;
```

[image]

A more elegant solution is to use ST_Relate with the DE9IM matrix `'1********'` (the overlap between the interiors of the lines is 1D - a line):

```
select l1.id as id1, l2.id as id2,
       st_intersection(l1.geometry, l2.geometry) as pure_overlaps
from lines l1, lines l2
where l1.id < l2.id and
      st_relate(l1.geometry, l2.geometry, '1********');
```

[image]

For finding overlapping lines between two layers QGIS has more to offer.
You can identify the lines that overlap by using the QGIS ***Intersection*** (overlay) algorithm.

1. Make sure that both layers have identifying attributes (e.g. one attribute with the name `id`).
2. Select the first line layer as *Input layer*
3. Select the second line layer as *Overlay layer*
4. Specify `other_` in the *Overlay fields prefix* to easily differentiate the attributes/fields from the two layers in the result.

The result will only contain the overlapping segments, and if you open the attribute table of the result layer, you will be able to see which lines from the second layer overlap the first one by looking at the field `other_id` from the second layer.

Lines that only touch will not "match", so only truly overlapping lines are found.

An even more flexible alternative is the QGIS ***Join attributes by location*** algorithm.  Here you can specify the type of relationship, and *overlaps* is one of them.

The resulting layer contains joined line geometries, with attributes from the two overlapping lines. If the attributes of the second line layer are NULL in the result, there are no lines in the second layer that overlap this line from the first layer.

Comment: He is only working with one layer

Comment: @Jakob What if he's a she? Or within that range? Or outside?

Comment: Then I might be wrong, not the first or last time ...

Comment: @Jakob fair enough ,) "*OP is working with one layer*" may be a good way to be on the safe side?

Comment: Safe side for me is not to jaywalk when a truck is parsing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test the overlap on the same layer, you can use SQL to find which parts of the lines do overlap.

Open Databasemanager and go to Virtual Layers.

Open an SQL-window and paste following code:

```sql
select st_intersection(l1.geometry, l2.geometry) as geometry, l1.fid as l1_id, l2.fid as l2_id 
from line_layer as l1, line_layer as l2
where l1.fid <> l2.fid and covers(l1.geometry, l2.geometry)
```

Change twice `line_layer` to your layername.
And change four times `fid` to the `ID` of your layer

Check *'load as new layer'*

The result gives you the shared geometry and the id of the two overlapping lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a QGIS Virtual Layer to both get an attribute table with id of the geometries covering each other and maps showing where the geometry cover is.

You can make a new Virtual Layer from the Data Source Manager. Use this SQL code:

```sql
select m1.fid id1, m2.fid id2, st_length(m1.geometry) length1, st_length(m2.geometry) length2, m1.geometry 
from mylines m1
inner join mylines m2 on st_covers(m1.geometry, m2.geometry)
where m1.fid <> m2.fid
```

**where**
`mylines` is you layername,
`fid` is a unique id in your layer,
`id1` and `id2` are just alias for `fid`.

Length will tell you the which one of the geometries are the smallest. Pictured in the map is `m1.geometry`, you make another map showing `m2.geometry`:

```sql
select m1.fid id1, m2.fid id2, st_length(m2.geometry) length1, st_length(m2.geometry) length2, m1.geometry 
from mylines m1
inner join mylines m2 on st_covers(m1.geometry, m2.geometry)
where m1.fid <> m2.fid
```

[image: example1]

Above are four lines. Line 2 is covering the part of line 0 (the bottom vertical segment)

[image: example2]

Above first SQL showing m1

[image: example3]

Second SQL showing m2

[image: example4]

Above attribute table showing cover list

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and according to me, the best way to solve it is to use **v.clean** GRASS tool with the following parameters.

Input feature type: line

Cleaning tool: break

The line will be divided into segments at the overlapping points. Then you can use "Delete duplicate geometries"

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I used this code but it isn't work.
My code is:

select l1.id as id1, l2.id as id2,
  st_intersection(l1.geometry, l2.geometry) as geometry
  from line l1, line l2
  where
    (st_overlaps(l1.geometry, l2.geometry) or
     st_contains(l1.geometry, l2.geometry) or
     st_within(l1.geometry, l2.geometry)
    )
     and l1.id < l2.id;

[image]

Are there any problems with my code or is this code affected by Qgis 3.6?