# Check geometries of line

Tags: qgis-3, network-analyst, geometric-network

I am working with hydraulic network. I have a pipes network. I am trying to check it's geometries. 
I have searched many related documents, I know topolygon tool and check geometries, but it only helps to detect error in the case one, the result is duplicate pipes.

[image]

Is there any methods to detect error in the case two?

Comment: If your goal is to find overlapping line check this answer : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354029/find-overlapping-lines-in-same-layer

Comment: @J.R  That is all I am looking for. Thanks so much